# Copy files from sftp server to ADLS via databricks

Tags: dataframe, azure, pyspark, databricks

I want to copy files from an sftp server to ADLS via databricks. I copied the file into a temp dbfs folder but I can't write it into ADLS. Is there a better way to do this using databricks.

```
Import pysftp

files = sftp.listdir("/home/folder/my_files")
dbfs_path = 'my_temp_folder' os.makedirs(dbfs_path, exist_ok=True)

for f in files: 
    remote_file_path="home/folder/my_files" 
    Local_file = dbfs_path + "/" + f sftp.get(remote_file_path, Local_file)
```

Comment: Please share the code which you have used so far.

Comment: I understand that you managed to copy the file from your sftp server to DBFS, using python.
Could you share how you are trying to write to ADLS. Are you using mountpoints, Azure SDK, etc?

Comment: Could you please provide the approach what you have tried?

Comment: @AnupamChand I have added the code to the original thanks.

Comment: @BernardJesop I have added the code to it

Comment: what do you mean by you cannot write it to ADLS? Are you getting an error of some sort? Did you try writing the files directly to ADLS instead of dbfs? What was the error/issue there?

Comment: I tried writing it directly to ADLS but it didn't work.  If you had this issue how will you do it

Comment: We are still missing information to help you. We would require, more details about the configuration of your ADLS and its integration with Databricks, if any. For instance, how do you authenticate, do you use an identity with RBAC roles, do you have ACLs configured?
It could be that the integration with ADLS has been abstracted, by your databricks admins, thanks to Databricks mountpoints.
Unfortunately, currently, we don't have enough information to help you.

Answer (score 0):

After copying to the DBFS path from the SFTP server, you need to copy it to the ADLS path. Follow the procedure below:

Mount the ADLS account using the code below:

```py
dbutils.fs.mount(
    source="wasbs://<containerName>@<storageaccountName>.blob.core.windows.net/",
    mount_point="/mnt/<mountName>",
    extra_configs={
f"fs.azure.account.key.<storageaccountName>.blob.core.windows.net":"<Access-Key>"  
  }
)
```

Use the command below to copy files:

```
dbutils.fs.cp(dbfs_temp_path, adls_destination_path, recurse=True)
```

This will successfully copy the files from the DBFS path to the ADLS account.

[image]

Here is the complete code for your reference:

```
import pysftp

sftp_host = '<hostName>'
sftp_port = 22
sftp_username = '<userName>'
sftp_password = '<password>'
sftp_folder = 'files'
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None   
dbfs_temp_path = '<dbfsPath>'
adls_destination_path='/dbfs/mnt/<mountPoint>'

with pysftp.Connection(host=sftp_host, port=sftp_port, username=sftp_username, password=sftp_password, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:

    files = sftp.listdir(sftp_folder)
    for file_name in files:
        sftp_path = sftp_folder + '/' + file_name
        dbfs_path = dbfs_temp_path + '/' + file_name
        print('sftpPath:',sftp_path)
        sftp.get(sftp_path, dbfs_path)

dbutils.fs.cp(dbfs_temp_path, adls_destination_path, recurse=True)
```

It is better to use Azure Data Factory to copy files from [SFTP server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sftp?tabs=data-factory) to ADLS Gen2 account compared to Databricks.